# How to do single button action for multi sheet (tabs) excel using VB script?

Tags: excel, vba, basic

I am a beginner in VB script and I have a excel sheet with multi tab . I have created a one button inside one excel sheet . Another sheets having some table . I want to generate some code inside a file with those excel tables using a simple button .

**For example :**

This excel book have one tab called Generate . Inside Generate i have created one button .

[image]

I have another tab named country which contain a table for country list

[image]

I have another tab also named car which contain a table for car list

[image]

Now i want to create a file "output.txt" which should create with some code from both tabs (country and vehicle )when click Generate code button .

My **output.txt** format :

```
*from sheet1 Country*/

VAR const US[] =
{
   0x0,/*binary 00000*/
   0xB,/*binary 01011*/
   0x3,/*binary 00011*/
   0x3,/*binary 00011*/
   0xB,/*binary 01011*/
   1xB /*binary 11011*/
};

//need to crate hexa array for Uk,france,brazil and india   

VAR DefaultCountry[] =
{
  invalid,
  UK,
  Brazil,
  Brazil,
  UK,
  India
};

/* from sheet2 car */

VAR const polo[] =
{

};

//need to crate hexa array for BMW,i20,Swift and wagnor   

VAR DefaultCAR[] =
{
  invalid,
  BMW,
  Swift,
  Swift,
  BMW,
  Wagnor
}
```

**excelsheet.txt** format :

```
const exceldetails[Maxindex] = 
       {
         /* index 0 */
         /* index 1 */
        { 
         { UK, India, brazil,eMaxNoOfcountry, eMaxNoOfcountry},
          {BMW, Wagnor, Swift,eMaxNoOfcar,eMaxNoOfcar },
          index1,
        },
         /*index 2*/
         etc..
    };
```

1. If the column has  "-" , it should take 0 value and if it is integer , it should take 1 value and print the hexa value and binary value both

   **eg:** for country index 0 : - - - - - => binary : 00000 => hexa : 0x0
    index 1 : - 1 - 3 2 => binary : 01011 => hexa : 0xB

   **Array name :** VAR const US[],france etc.. VAR const polo[],swift etc..
2. If the column contain 1 , It is default value and print the default value column name for each index in array

   **array name :** VAR DefaultCountry[],VAR DefaultCAR[])
3. Create another file "exceldetails.txt" and write the order of each country and car details in array . If "-" present take as eMaxNoOf.

   **array name :** exceldetails[Maxindex])

How to do this ? Any help ? Any Reference also be helpful . How to use one button for taking table values from multi tabs?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?  Forgetting the button for now, can you do everything else?

Comment: yes . i want to know how to traverse each tabs (sheets) tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you a little snippet code  that doesn't answer all your question but only when you convert decimal value in binary and in hex. I don't understood good all what you want

```
Sub test()

'binary code and hex code
With Application.WorksheetFunction ' with this row you can use the functions Dec2Bin, Dec2Hex 

    'convert decimal in binary
    Cells(1, 1) = .Dec2Bin(Cells(1, 2)) ' input 3 -> out: 11

    'convert binary in hex
    Cells(2, 1) = .Dec2Hex(Cells(2, 2)) ' input 11 -> out B

End With
End Sub
```

this is the snippet code where you can create and write into file txt

```
Sub test()
'create and write into file txt
'when you execute again the macro the file is overwritten
Dim fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("yourPath\MyFile.txt", True, True)
    Fileout.Write "your string goes here"
    Fileout.Close
End Sub
```

I created two macro so you can try every single macro. You have to create an only macro where there is all the code...

hope this helps

EDIT to answer your commento
If you want work into sheet below there is an example

```
Sub test()

Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim i, r, numRows, numColumns As Long

'set sh1 and the works it
Set sh1 = Sheets("Country") ' sheet name

'count how many rows there are into sheet1
'numRows = sh1.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeContants).Count
numRows = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox numRows

'count how many columns there are into sheet1
numColumns = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'MsgBox numColumns

With sh1
For j = 2 To numColumns
   For i = 2 To numRows - 1
        If .Cells(i, j) = "-" Then

            'msgbox "the item into cell is empity: "
            'you code..
        Else
            'msgbox "the item into cells is: " & .cells(i,j)
            'your code...

        End If
    Next i
Next j
End With

'----repeat operation for the sheet2
'set sh2 and the works it
Set sh2 = Sheets("car") ' sheet name

'count how many rows there are into sheet2
numRows = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox numRows

'count how many columns there are into sheet2
numColumns = sh2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'MsgBox numColumns

With sh2
For j = 2 To numColumns
    For i = 2 To numRows - 1
        If .Cells(i, j) = "-" Then

            'msgbox "the item into cell is empity: "
            'you code..
        Else
            'msgbox "the item into cells is: " & .cells(i,j)
            'your code...

        End If
    Next i
Next j
End With

End Sub
```

There are two for loop because One use the columns and the other the rows...

Comment: Thanks for your answer . could you please explain how to get data from each traverse each tabs (sheets) tables . fo example in my case , country and car are the tabs (sheets) contain tables .

Comment: @user2986042 i have edited my answer and i hope this helps